# React nested object array inner object is somehow linked to all object elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested

I've got a nested object that somehow retains a linkage to a profile object. Every time I call myMethod and makes changes to userObj, these changes are reflected in all elements of the nested object. For example, allProfiles['a'] and allProfiles['b'] have the same values for allProfiles[][].userObj properties. This only happens with the userObj data, everything is works as expected. The following snippet duplicates the issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactDOM, render } from 'react-dom';

export const userProfile = {
  address1: { label: "Local", data: null },
  address2: { label: "World", data: null },
};

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      profiles: {}
    };
    this.addProfile = this.addProfile.bind(this);
  }

  addProfile() {
    const { counter, profiles } = this.state;
    let new_user = Object.assign({}, userProfile);
    new_user.address1.data = counter * 5;
    const profile_id = 1;
    const user_id = counter;

    const new_profile = {};
    const show = true;
    new_profile[profile_id] = { show };
    new_profile[profile_id] = new_user;
    profiles[user_id] = new_profile;
    this.setState({ counter: user_id + 1, profiles });
  }

  render() {
    const profile_id = 1;
    const ctr = this.state.counter;
    return (
      <div>
        <div><button onClick={this.addProfile}>add profile</button></div>
        <div>profile 0 data:
          {ctr > 0 ? this.state.profiles[0][profile_id].address1.data : null}</div>
        <div>profile {ctr} data:
          {ctr > 0 ? this.state.profiles[ctr - 1][profile_id].address1.data : null}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default (Toggle);
render(<Toggle />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can you post the full (compilable) code?

Comment: I have added a snippet that duplicates the issue

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign({}, userProfile)` only creates a shallow copy of `userProfile`, meaning `new_user.address1` and `userProfile.address1` are still referencing the same object.

To properly clone the `address1` and `address2` objects, you need to do

```
const new_user = Object.entries(userProfile).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = { ...value }; // create a shallow copy of the nested object
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This should fix your problem but there's a lot of weird things going on in your code, like assigning `new_profile[profile_id]` consecutively.

Comment: thanks. I had tried using cloneDeep yesterday without seeing any difference. However, tried it on this example and it solved the problem. The 'weird' code is mostly me trying to simplify the actual code to create this example.